# Get records from MongoDB based on count and group

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get records from MongoDB using [MongoDB native driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native), where count `user` more than some number  and `_id` between ObjectID range and group by `user`. My code looks like this:

```
         {
            $match: {
                _id: {
                    $gte: objectIDMin,
                    $lt: objectIDMax
                },
                count: {
                    $gt: someNumber
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $group : {
                _id: '$user',
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        },
        {
            $sort : { 'count' : -1}
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your sample ObjectID's?

Comment: @divine E.g What I give min is 5a1b55800000000000000000, max 5a42e2800000000000000000. In db 59fd695079ca40303fb787b4, but as I mention this filter alone works, but not count.

Comment: what are the objectId's you get in result, when you just place count: {
                    $gt: someNumber
                } and trigger the find query?

Comment: Currently returns nothing with the query above, Somehow it did work yesterday. I updated the question.

Comment: So if I remove _id condition and move `group` before `match` it returns counts per user.